# Why can a user on OS X open some directories of other users?

Tags: macos, permission, user-account

I run OS X Yosemite (10.10.3). From the sysadmin account, I created a standard account. This account can't open standard directories like *Documents* or *Pictures* in the admin’s user folder. It can access however every single folder and document that does not belong to this preinstalled standard folders. Changing folder permissions in the admin account does not change anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that *Documents* etc. has `+` sign when you `ls -la ~`. Check out **ACL**  (Access Control Lists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to prevent the access is by **Get Info..** (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> on directory and setting the permissions there.

To prevent other user from viewing your files, settings should look like:

- **username(me)** read / write
- **everyone** no access

Note: remove all the other positions like group etc.

Comment: As I wrote "Changing folder permissions in the admin account does not change anything."

Comment: Note: You need to remove "staff" and leave only "me" and "everyone", set "everyone" to no access.

Comment: I can't remove "staff", it tells me I have no right to do so although I am an admin.

Comment: @lejonet click on the padlock in the lower right corner, You'll be asked for Your admin password.